# What is the best way to help a user map fields between two entities?

Tags: usability, data-mapping

[image]

If you look at attached images, there are two XML files left and right mapped automatically by system with some logic.

But if you see closely **creation date** and **date of birth** are getting mapped with the same field i.e. **src_dateofbirth** because system check and match "date" text and put some extra logic, but in this case it is incorrect and need user intervention.

Most of the time there will be 80+ fields both side and mapping and correction manually is messy and unfriendly.

So I have concluded few solutions and would like **community** to help.

What I will do

1. Map the fields automatically
2. If multiple fields from left table are getting mapped with a single entity of right table. Show some visual clue. [current system doesn't provide  this feature]
3. If there is some fields not mapped, highlight[current system doesn't provide this feature]
4. What else?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest giving the user a single problematic field at a time and showing them the options for fixing it.

Then, AFTER they've fixed any fields that could not be mapped automatically, show them the full list. (So that they can look it over and confirm that it is correct.)